# Why does (moderators) tag on meta behave differently from other tags?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

When I click on the [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) tag here on meta:

- I see that it contains one question.
- No tag-wiki is displayed. (And neither is the possibility to edit the tag-wiki.)
- When I try to find this tag in the [list of tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags), it is not shown there. (It is not displayed when searching for the tag, I could not find it, when I ordered the tags [by name](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags?page=2&tab=name) and it is not shown among [new tags](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags?tab=new).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a caching issue. When a tag is first created on a site (especially by means like an automated system, such as what generated the announcement for the election), the process for categorizing tags may not have caught up. [election](/questions/tagged/election) was in a similar boat at first, but because I posted the [Election Q&A](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/908/2013-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) with the tag, it then realized it is indeed a real tag and updated itself.

Had an edit to insert the tag into this report (and consequently remove it) not been done, then some hours may have passed before rightness would've asserted itself naturally.